# Approach for mapping a list of values with internal looping without outputting multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I'm trying to functionally loop a list of numbers, checking each number against a list of rules to output an updated list consisting of numbers and strings. I'm having trouble understanding how I can combine the 2 loops without duplicating the number of items added (currently 1 * 3 iterations per number :/), I also get `undefined` for all entries.

Can someone point me to the technique required to achieve this, the output should be `[1, 2, 'In', 4, 'Out', 'In', 7, 8, 'In', 'Out', 11, 'In', 13, 14, 'InOut']`

Code:

```
const range = (start, end) => Array.from({ length: end }, (_, i) => i + start)
const rules = [[3, 'In'], [5, 'Out'], [15, 'InOut']]

function output(range, markers) {
  return range.map(num => {

    markers.forEach(([div, text]) => {
      if(num % div === 0) return text
      return num
    })

  })
}

output(range(1, 10), rules)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), as that is for executing a function on each element of an array, like a map that doesn't return anything.

What you should do is look for the marker, and return the substitution if you find it.

That's what [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will do for you:

```js
const range = (start, end) => Array.from({ length: end - (start-1) }, (_, i) => i + start)
const rules = [[15, 'InOut'], [5, 'Out'], [3, 'In']]

function output(range, markers) {

 return range.map(num => {

    let item = markers.find(marker => num % marker[0] === 0);
    
    if(item){
      return item[1];
    }
    return num;
  })
}

console.log(output(range(1, 30), rules))
```

Also, order your rules by number of divisors, so prime numbers will be at the end. This is because `find` takes the first hit, so you want it to find the numbers with the most divisors first.